# error installing postgresql with windows7

Tags: postgresql, installation

guys while installing posqresql I got those 2 error message

[image: first error messeage]

and when I clicked ok then the second error message displayed on my screen

[image: second error message]

and now when I try to connect with my DB using my terminal or git bash I got another error message which is

[image: error in terminal]

So, what could I do to solve this problem?

please note that I have tried to re-install postgres

Answer (score 1):

Try these and let us know the results;

```
netstat -an | find /I "5432"

pg_isready

psql -U postgres
```

Comment: no response 
```netstat -an | find /I "5432"
find: ‘/I’: No such file or directory
find: ‘5432’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: and when I tried to connect with my db it responsed with the same error message

Comment: Hi, ok that tells me that Postgresql is not running. You could run "services.msc" and look for Postgresql  and try to start it. Worth trying. If that doesn't work I'm not sure. It does seem like it hasn't installed correctly. Is the issue something like admin rights?

Comment: I can confirm that it's not about admin right because there is only one admin for this PC whom is me
no either postgresql is not there at servvices.mc so what do you suggest ?

Comment: Good Luck!!  Anyway google "failed to load sql modules into the database cluster" gives quite a few options. The most likely looking answer was to create the data directory yourself completely new like (C:\PostgreSQL\data) and giving it full access for the group "Users", specifying that folder for the install. There are quite a few search results, hope you find one that works

Comment: thank you 
guys I have seen some recomindation with these steps it didn't work for me but I wanted to share it with you any way
when I went to (regedit.exe) and navigate to: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\pgsql-some version I know it has to be a bunch of folders here but I only found to folders only two so how could I fix it ?